# TouchListner ACTION_UP detection

Tags: android

I implemented the touch of an image . I would simply click on the image and when I click the image change the background ; when I remove the finger from the screen image back to first . The problem is that the ACTION_UP is recognized automatically a few seconds after the ACTION_DOWN even if my finger is still on the screen .

```
 imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getActionMasked()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   System.out.println("Touch Up");
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    System.out.println("Touch Down");
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doing some tests I found out that this thing happens to me only on a tablet with 4.4.4 . Everything works correctly in 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
               System.out.println("Touch Up");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                System.out.println("Touch Down");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I don't know whether event.getAction() and returning false is making a difference but just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ACTION_CANCEL`. This is called when the you remove your finger and gesture is aborted.